# Mockito assert after calling a void method

Tags: java, spring, mockito

```
@Test
public void shoudTestAssigneeSuccessfully() throws Exception {
    // given
    ApplicationUserDetails applicationUser = createApplicationUser();
    when(accessControlUtil.getLoggedInUser()).thenReturn(applicationUser);
    SomeEntity mockResponse = mock(SomeEntity.class);
    when(mockResponse.getAssignee()).thenReturn(applicationUser.getUsername());
    when(someRepository.findOneById(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(mockResponse));
    when(someRepository.save(any(SomeEntity .class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);
    // when
    someService.submitSomething(new SomeDataDto(SOME_ID, SOME_PARAM)); // A void method
    // then
    assertNull(mockResponse.getAssignee()); // ??
    verify(someRepository).save(any(SomeEntity .class));
}
```

Hi, I have this test which should basically check that the `Assignee` is null after performing the service call `submitSomething`. However, `submitSomething()` is a void method which internally sets the `Assignee` as null.
Please let me know what modifications I need in order to test this successfully.

Comment: for mocking methods which return nothing  a different Mockito method needs to be used. May be this will help - https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12

Comment: @Goro not required. The solution was fairly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out after a lot of trial & error.
The solution is fairly simple. Rather than mocking the `SomeEntity` directly, I'll have to create a new mock instance manually and set the `Assignee` manually first.

```
@Test
public void shoudTestAssigneeSuccessfully() throws Exception {
    // given
    ApplicationUserDetails applicationUser = createApplicationUser();
    when(accessControlUtil.getLoggedInUser()).thenReturn(applicationUser);

    SomeEntity mockResponse = new SomeEntity();
    mockResponse.setAssignee(applicationUser.getUsername());

    when(someRepository.findOneById(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(mockResponse));
    when(someRepository.save(any(SomeEntity .class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);
    // when
    someService.submitSomething(new SomeDataDto(SOME_ID, SOME_PARAM)); // A void method
    // then
    assertNull(mockResponse.getAssignee());
    verify(someRepository).save(any(SomeEntity .class));
}
```